# Unreal,Why can not have repeat value in Tarray,when used in UDeveloperSettings

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

```
UCLASS(config=Game, defaultconfig, meta=(DisplayName="GlobalSettings"))
class NIGHTMARE_API UNMSetting : public UDeveloperSettings
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    

    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere,Config,Category = "Global|Chip")
    TArray<TSoftClassPtr<UCardEntity>> InitCardEntities;
```

when i inset two same value in InitCardEntities,it seem right,but when i restart engine,check the value again.it's auto Remove Duplicates!!. so i check .ini file,it's look right.

i want know what happened,why,and how to use it.